# Как удалить Денвер?

Tags: denwer

Как удалить Денвер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Денвер полностью автономен. Поэтому удалив папку WebServers, вы удаляете и программу. Единственное, это из автозагрузчика убрать создание виртуального диска.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить виртуальный диск, нужно зайти в меню пуск -> выполнить и написать следующую строку: subst Z: /D, где Z: имя вашего виртуального диска.